# Shuffle songs in playlist only

Tags: ipod, playlist

Is there a way, in an 80GB iPod video (I think that's what it's called) to shuffle only the songs in my playlists?

In other words, when I drop into a playlist I want the songs to be shuffled, but when I drop into an album, I want to hear it in order.  Is that possible?

It seems like my only three choices for the `shuffle` setting are `songs`, `albums` and `off`.  Is there some other way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle is a global setting. You can't turn it on for playlists but not for albums.